# slicer list in excel and python

Tags: python, excel, list, slicers

does anyone know how to handle slicer list in excel from python. I´m working with some excel files, and one of them have some slicer list. When i run the next code

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wP =load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Arrontec\Desktop\Automatizacion\Request1.xlsx')
wB =load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Arrontec\Desktop\Automatizacion\CR_Accounts_Dashboard_V4_20170127_1.xlsx')
wPs = wP.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
wBs = wB.get_sheet_by_name('Request_Raw_Data')
for rrow in wPs.iter_rows():
    for cell in rrow:
        wBs[cell.coordinate] = cell.value
wB.save('CR_Accounts_Dashboard_V4_20170127_1.xlsx')
```

I receive this message

> UserWarning: Slicer List extension is not supported and will be
>   removed   warn(msg)

After some research i found that openpyxl do not support slicer list, someone know any library to work with the slicer.

Sorry for bad English and thanks for the help.